# Javascript code snippet will not run when placed after a separate function

Tags: javascript, html, date

I'm relatively new to Javascript and HTML5. I've written some Javascript that's supposed to change the 'min' attribute of a date input to today's date. In this same script file there is some code for a different html page above it.

```
var x = document.getElementById('add-to-cart');

x.onclick = function () {
    alert('Your item was added to the cart!'');

var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if(dd < 10){
  dd = '0' + dd;
}
if(mm < 10){
  mm = '0' + mm;
}

today = yyyy + "-" + mm + "-" + dd;
document.getElementById('pickup-date-input').setAttribute('min', today);
```

The x function is used on a different page. The date modifier will only work though if I put it in a separate .js file or if I put it above the other 3 lines of code and I can't figure out why. I've been told to use JQuery(I will eventually), but any help or explanation in this specific context would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The code you posted will result in syntax errors. Have you checked your developer console?

Comment: you can't assign today with a string, get a new variable to assign

Comment: Like I said it works perfectly fine. The code's not the issue. Its just the placement of it. If I delete the first 4 lines of code it runs exactly how I'd like it to run.